# Changing text in CSV file using Perl

Tags: perl

I know nothing about Perl. I have looked at some online tutorials and am at a loss for the following.

I do a query in PostgreSQL that saves to a CSV file. However, one element needs to be changed after the CSV file is created, and I have no idea how to do it.

The existing query results are like this

```
phone        date      time     staff email and customer ID -- my explanation 

1112223333,10/21/2013,3:00 AM,sklund@myemail.comSMIB010170 -- data in csv
```

After query is completed, the data in the time field must be converted to:

```
1112223333,10/21/2013,03:00am,sklund@myemail.comSMIB010170
```

As you can see, the time needs to be ammended to include a `0` if the hour is less than ten, and the `AM` must be changed to `am`.

Is there a simple Perl script that can do this? The lines of data, of course, will be different, as each line would reflect results of the query for the day.

If someone can point me to a tutorial, link, or help in this I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you need.

I assume you want the space before `AM` removed as well? You don't mention it in your question.

```
perl -pe 's/,(\d{1,2}):(\d\d)\s+([AP]M),/sprintf ",%02d:%02d%s,",$1,$2,lc $3/ei' mylogfile > newlogfile
```

Comment: Borodin -  Thank you for your help!  I tried your code as:  perl -pe 's/,(\d{1,2}):(\d\d)\s+([AP]M),/sprintf ",%02d:%02d%s,",$1,$2,lc $3/ei' phase1sys1.csv  > phase1sys1.csv and it wiped the file to a zero byte file.  I then tried: perl -pe 's/,(\d{1,2}):(\d\d)\s+([AP]M),/sprintf ",%02d:%02d%s,",$1,$2,lc $3/ei' phase1export.csv  > phase1sys1.csv
(renaming the original exported query) and it works wonderfully.

Comment: You can't run `any_program foo > foo` because first what shell will do is opening `foo` for writing so it will discard `foo` content. It is common shell's behavior.

Comment: Hynek -  Thanks for the clarification!  justintime -- thank you for the suggestion.  I believe I will rewrite the postgresql query to output to phase1export.  then the perl script will be: phase1export.csv > phase1sys1.csv  Then I can move both files to a history folder, amending the names to include datestamp.  Now I will have a way to add a level of troubleshooting in cases of issues.  Thanks to all of you for aiding me!